# Как запустить виртуальную среду и python файл в одном bat файле

Tags: python, cmd, bat, virtualenv, venv

Разрабатываю телеграм-бота в виртуальной среде. Захотел создать батник, который одновременно запускал бы виртуалку и уже в ней запускал файл. Но при запуске этого бат-файла запускается только виртуальная среда с ожиданием ввода команды. Вот так это выглядит:

(venv) d:\python\telegram_bot>

содержание бат файла.

```
cd d:\python\telegram_bot
d:
cmd /k .\venv\Scripts\activate& python main.py
echo main.py
```

так же пробовал вместо последней строчки писать это: "main.py","python main.py",python main.py

Comment: Если переделать в poetry проект, то можно запускать так: `poetry run python main.py` (но это уже в стиле "когда у тебя в руках молоток, все вокруг кажется гвоздями")

Comment: В конец файла `activate.bat` можно добавить `if not .%1. == .. python %1`, тогда просто вызываем `activate main.py`.

Comment: @AlexTitov спасибо, помогло)